# How can I avoid a ripple effect from changing a concrete struct to generic?

Tags: generics, rust, traits

I have a configuration struct that looks like this:

```
struct Conf {
    list: Vec<String>,
}
```

The implementation was internally populating the `list` member, but now I have decided that I want to delegate that task to another object.  So I have:

```
trait ListBuilder {
    fn build(&self, list: &mut Vec<String>);
}

struct Conf<T: Sized + ListBuilder> {
    list: Vec<String>,
    builder: T,
}

impl<T> Conf<T>
where
    T: Sized + ListBuilder,
{
    fn init(&mut self) {
        self.builder.build(&mut self.list);
    }
}

impl<T> Conf<T>
where
    T: Sized + ListBuilder,
{
    pub fn new(lb: T) -> Self {
        let mut c = Conf {
            list: vec![],
            builder: lb,
        };
        c.init();
        c
    }
}
```

That seems to work fine, but now *everywhere* that I use `Conf`, I have to change it:

```
fn do_something(c: &Conf) {
    // ...
}
```

becomes

```
fn do_something<T>(c: &Conf<T>)
where
    T: ListBuilder,
{
    // ...
}
```

Since I have many such functions, this conversion is painful, especially since most usages of the `Conf` class don't care about the `ListBuilder` - it's an implementation detail. I'm concerned that if I add another generic type to `Conf`, now I have to go back and add another generic parameter everywhere.  Is there any way to avoid this?

I know that I could use a closure instead for the list builder, but I have the added constraint that my `Conf` struct needs to be `Clone`, and the actual builder implementation is more complex and has several functions and some state in the builder, which makes a closure approach unwieldy.

Comment: It's not required to have the bound `Sized`; that's the default.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the [trait object](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html) `Box<dyn ListBuilder>` to hide the type of the builder. Some of the consequences are dynamic dispatch (calls to the `build` method will go through a virtual function table), additional memory allocation (boxed trait object), and some [restrictions on the trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html#object-safety-is-required-for-trait-objects)  `ListBuilder`.

```
trait ListBuilder {
    fn build(&self, list: &mut Vec<String>);
}

struct Conf {
    list: Vec<String>,
    builder: Box<dyn ListBuilder>,
}

impl Conf {
    fn init(&mut self) {
        self.builder.build(&mut self.list);
    }
}

impl Conf {
    pub fn new<T: ListBuilder + 'static>(lb: T) -> Self {
        let mut c = Conf {
            list: vec![],
            builder: Box::new(lb),
        };
        c.init();
        c
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that was pretty much what I needed.  My ListBuilder also needed to implement Clone, which I solved using the method described here: https://users.rust-lang.org/t/solved-is-it-possible-to-clone-a-boxed-trait-object/1714/6

Answer (score 11):

While generic types can seem to "infect" the rest of your code, that's exactly why they are beneficial! The compiler knowledge about how big and specifically what type is used allow it to make better optimization decisions.

That being said, it can be annoying! If you have a small number of types that implement your trait, you can also construct an enum of those types and delegate to the child implementations:

```rust
enum MyBuilders {
    User(FromUser),
    File(FromFile),
}

impl ListBuilder for MyBuilders {
    fn build(&self, list: &mut Vec<String>) {
        use MyBuilders::*;
        match self {
            User(u) => u.build(list),
            File(f) => f.build(list),
        }
    }
}

// Support code

trait ListBuilder {
    fn build(&self, list: &mut Vec<String>);
}

struct FromUser;
impl ListBuilder for FromUser {
    fn build(&self, list: &mut Vec<String>) {}
}

struct FromFile;
impl ListBuilder for FromFile {
    fn build(&self, list: &mut Vec<String>) {}
}
```

Now the concrete type would be `Conf<MyBuilders>`, which you can use a type alias to hide.

I've used this to good effect when I wanted to be able to inject test implementations into code during testing, but had a fixed set of implementations that were used in the production code.

The [enum_dispatch crate](https://crates.io/crates/enum_dispatch) helps construct this pattern.