# How to store a reference without having to deal with lifetimes?

Tags: rust, symbols, ffi, lifetime

As suggested by [the `dynamic_reload` crate's example](https://github.com/emoon/dynamic_reload), I collected `Symbol`s instead of extracting them every time, but `Symbol` requires a lifetime. Using a lifetime changes method signatures and breaks the compatibility with method `DynamicReload::update`.

Is it a valid workaround to use `std::mem::transmute` to change `Symbol`'s lifetime to `'static`?

```
extern crate dynamic_reload;

use dynamic_reload::{DynamicReload, Lib, Symbol, Search, PlatformName, UpdateState};
use std::sync::Arc;
use std::time::Duration;
use std::thread;
use std::mem::transmute;

struct Plugins {
    plugins: Vec<(Arc<Lib>, Arc<Symbol<'static, extern "C" fn() -> i32>>)>,
}

impl Plugins {
    fn add_plugin(&mut self, plugin: &Arc<Lib>) {
        match unsafe { plugin.lib.get(b"shared_fun\0") } {
            Ok(temp) => {
                let f: Symbol<extern "C" fn() -> i32> = temp;
                self.plugins.push((plugin.clone(), Arc::new(unsafe { transmute(f) })));
            },
            Err(e) => println!("Failed to load symbol: {:?}", e),
        }
    }

    fn unload_plugins(&mut self, lib: &Arc<Lib>) {
        for i in (0..self.plugins.len()).rev() {
            if &self.plugins[i].0 == lib {
                self.plugins.swap_remove(i);
            }
        }
    }

    fn reload_plugin(&mut self, lib: &Arc<Lib>) {
        Self::add_plugin(self, lib);
    }

    // called when a lib needs to be reloaded.
    fn reload_callback(&mut self, state: UpdateState, lib: Option<&Arc<Lib>>) {
        match state {
            UpdateState::Before => Self::unload_plugins(self, lib.unwrap()),
            UpdateState::After => Self::reload_plugin(self, lib.unwrap()),
            UpdateState::ReloadFailed(_) => println!("Failed to reload"),
        }
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut plugs = Plugins { plugins: Vec::new() };

    // Setup the reload handler. A temporary directory will be created inside the target/debug
    // where plugins will be loaded from. That is because on some OS:es loading a shared lib
    // will lock the file so we can't overwrite it so this works around that issue.
    let mut reload_handler = DynamicReload::new(Some(vec!["target/debug"]),
                                                Some("target/debug"),
                                                Search::Default);

    // test_shared is generated in build.rs
    match reload_handler.add_library("test_shared", PlatformName::Yes) {
        Ok(lib) => plugs.add_plugin(&lib),
        Err(e) => {
            println!("Unable to load dynamic lib, err {:?}", e);
            return;
        }
    }

    //
    // While this is running (printing a number) change return value in file src/test_shared.rs
    // build the project with cargo build and notice that this code will now return the new value
    //
    loop {
        reload_handler.update(Plugins::reload_callback, &mut plugs);

        if plugs.plugins.len() > 0 {
            let fun = &plugs.plugins[0].1;
            println!("Value {}", fun());
        }

        // Wait for 0.5 sec
        thread::sleep(Duration::from_millis(500));
    }
}
```

I still have to keep `Arc<Lib>` inside the vector because `Symbol` doesn't implement `PartialEq`.

Comment: Why do not you box them?

Comment: @Boiethios do you mean Arc<Box<Symbol<'a, extern...>>> ? Or do you mean to use the Box only when inserting Symbol insite the Vec? But the type definition will still contain a lifetime...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I didn't read the definition of [`Symbol`](https://docs.rs/dynamic_reload/0.3.0/dynamic_reload/struct.Symbol.html)...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How to store a reference without having to deal with lifetimes?

The answer in 98% of the cases is: **you don't**. Lifetimes are one of the biggest reasons to use Rust. Lifetimes enforce, *at compile time*, that your references will always refer to something that is valid. If you wish to "ignore" lifetimes, then perhaps Rust may not the best language to realize a particular design. You may need to pick a different language or design.

> Is it a valid workaround to use `std::mem::transmute` to change `Symbol`'s lifetime to `'static`?

`transmute` is The Big Hammer, suitable for all sorts of good and bad ideas and implementations. I would encourage never using it directly, but instead wrapping it in a layer of abstraction that somehow helps you enforce the appropriate restrictions that make that particular transmute correct.

If you choose to use `transmute`, you are assuming the *full responsibility* that the compiler previously had. It will be up to you to ensure that the reference is **always** valid, otherwise you are invoking undefined behavior and your program is allowed to do any number of Very Bad things.

---

For your specific case, you *may* be able to use [the Rental crate](https://crates.io/crates/rental) to keep around "the library" and "references into the library" in a single struct that hides the lifetimes of the `Symbol`s. In fact, Rental uses [libloading](https://crates.io/crates/libloading) as the motivating example and libloading powers dynamic_reload. See
[Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423) for more details and pitfalls.

I'm not optimistic that this will work because [`DynamicReload::update`](https://docs.rs/dynamic_reload/0.3.0/dynamic_reload/struct.DynamicReload.html#method.update) requires a `&mut self`. During that method call, it could easily invalidate all of the existing references.

See also:

- [Why can't I store a value and a reference to that value in the same struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32300132/155423)
- [How can I avoid a ripple effect from changing a concrete struct to generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912349/155423)

Comment: Thank you very much for your explanation