# Struct initialization in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm building an easy to use interface for the libuvc camera-library in Rust. I want to define a `Camera` type that is easy to set up. I'm using libuvc-rs as an interface to the libuvc c-library. Setting up a camera using libuvc requires calling a number of functions that each return handles used to perform different functions in the uvc library. My struct `UvcCamera`, therefore, contains one of each of these types for operation:

```rust
pub struct UvcCamera<'a> {
    ctx: uvc::Context<'a>,
    dev: uvc::Device<'a>,
    devh: uvc::DeviceHandle<'a>,
    streamh: uvc::StreamHandle<'a>,
}
```

I cannot create a function that legally initializes these variables. Importantly, the function doesn't return a reference but an owned object. The struct members are also not references but owned objects. No matter the approach I choose, I end up with some kind of borrowing error (and I have searched the internet endlessly for similar problems but without luck). The most straightforward implementation is shown below:

```rust
impl<'a> UvcCamera<'a> {

    pub fn new() -> uvc::Result<UvcCamera<'a>> {
        let serial = UvcCamera::serial_number_from_uid(1)?;
        let ctx: uvc::Context<'a> = uvc::Context::new()?;
        let dev = ctx.find_device(None, None, Some(&serial))?;
        let devh = dev.open()?;

        let format = uvc::StreamFormat {
            width: 640,
            height: 480,
            fps: 60,
            format: uvc::FrameFormat::MJPEG,
        };

        let streamh = devh.get_stream_handle_with_format(format)?;
        Ok(UvcCamera { ctx, dev, devh, streamh })
    }
```

This results in the error

```
error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `devh`
  --> src/camera.rs:36:9
   |
35 |         let streamh = devh.get_stream_handle_with_format(format)?;
   |                       ---- `devh` is borrowed here
36 |         Ok(UvcCamera { ctx, dev, devh, streamh })
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `dev`
  --> src/camera.rs:36:9
   |
26 |         let devh = dev.open()?;
   |                    --- `dev` is borrowed here
...
36 |         Ok(UvcCamera { ctx, dev, devh, streamh })
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `ctx`
  --> src/camera.rs:36:9
   |
25 |         let dev = ctx.find_device(None, None, Some(&serial))?;
   |                   --- `ctx` is borrowed here
...
36 |         Ok(UvcCamera { ctx, dev, devh, streamh })
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `ctx` because it is borrowed
  --> src/camera.rs:36:24
   |
20 | impl<'a> UvcCamera<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
25 |         let dev = ctx.find_device(None, None, Some(&serial))?;
   |                   --- borrow of `ctx` occurs here
...
36 |         Ok(UvcCamera { ctx, dev, devh, streamh })
   |         ---------------^^^-----------------------
   |         |              |
   |         |              move out of `ctx` occurs here
   |         returning this value requires that `ctx` is borrowed for `'a`

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `dev` because it is borrowed
  --> src/camera.rs:36:29
   |
20 | impl<'a> UvcCamera<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
26 |         let devh = dev.open()?;
   |                    --- borrow of `dev` occurs here
...
36 |         Ok(UvcCamera { ctx, dev, devh, streamh })
   |         --------------------^^^------------------
   |         |                   |
   |         |                   move out of `dev` occurs here
   |         returning this value requires that `dev` is borrowed for `'a`

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `devh` because it is borrowed
  --> src/camera.rs:36:34
   |
20 | impl<'a> UvcCamera<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
35 |         let streamh = devh.get_stream_handle_with_format(format)?;
   |                       ---- borrow of `devh` occurs here
36 |         Ok(UvcCamera { ctx, dev, devh, streamh })
   |         -------------------------^^^^------------
   |         |                        |
   |         |                        move out of `devh` occurs here
   |         returning this value requires that `devh` is borrowed for `'a`

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `devh`
  --> src/camera.rs:36:9
   |
35 |         let streamh = devh.get_stream_handle_with_format(format)?;
   |                       ---- `devh` is borrowed here
36 |         Ok(UvcCamera { ctx, dev, devh, streamh })
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `dev`
  --> src/camera.rs:36:9
   |
26 |         let devh = dev.open()?;
   |                    --- `dev` is borrowed here
...
36 |         Ok(UvcCamera { ctx, dev, devh, streamh })
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0515]: cannot return value referencing local variable `ctx`
  --> src/camera.rs:36:9
   |
25 |         let dev = ctx.find_device(None, None, Some(&serial))?;
   |                   --- `ctx` is borrowed here
...
36 |         Ok(UvcCamera { ctx, dev, devh, streamh })
   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returns a value referencing data owned by the current function

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `ctx` because it is borrowed
  --> src/camera.rs:36:24
   |
20 | impl<'a> UvcCamera<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
25 |         let dev = ctx.find_device(None, None, Some(&serial))?;
   |                   --- borrow of `ctx` occurs here
...
36 |         Ok(UvcCamera { ctx, dev, devh, streamh })
   |         ---------------^^^-----------------------
   |         |              |
   |         |              move out of `ctx` occurs here
   |         returning this value requires that `ctx` is borrowed for `'a`

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `dev` because it is borrowed
  --> src/camera.rs:36:29
   |
20 | impl<'a> UvcCamera<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
26 |         let devh = dev.open()?;
   |                    --- borrow of `dev` occurs here
...
36 |         Ok(UvcCamera { ctx, dev, devh, streamh })
   |         --------------------^^^------------------
   |         |                   |
   |         |                   move out of `dev` occurs here
   |         returning this value requires that `dev` is borrowed for `'a`

error[E0505]: cannot move out of `devh` because it is borrowed
  --> src/camera.rs:36:34
   |
20 | impl<'a> UvcCamera<'a> {
   |      -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
35 |         let streamh = devh.get_stream_handle_with_format(format)?;
   |                       ---- borrow of `devh` occurs here
36 |         Ok(UvcCamera { ctx, dev, devh, streamh })
   |         -------------------------^^^^------------
   |         |                        |
   |         |                        move out of `devh` occurs here
   |         returning this value requires that `devh` is borrowed for `'a`
```

Importantly, all the libuvc types implement `Drop` (logical since they hold references that need to be freed) and therefore can't derive `Copy`. Is there any way constructing this kind of type is possible?

Comment: Why not pass in the value of `devh` into the `new` function instead of calling it there?

Comment: I guess that would be possible but the point of the camera-type is to abstract those details away. Eventually, I would like to add interfaces to other libraries - therefore it would make most sense to hide the library-specific code in the implementation.

Comment: Perhaps [How to store a reference without having to deal with lifetimes?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49300618/155423) shows one solution, using the Rental crate

Comment: I'm still learning Rust but I'm not using references in my struct or the new function - specifically because of these other questions.

Comment: *I'm not using references in my struct* — yes, you are. `<'a>` means that your structs contain one or more references with the lifetime `'a`. Every single member of your `UvcCamera` contains at least one reference.

Comment: Ah thanks! I did not realize that. Then it makes much more sense and I guess I can use the suggested posts to find the answers I need.