# How to return an inner type variant reference from an enum without having generics all over the place?

Tags: rust

Here are 2 examples that do not compile:

```rust
type Common<K, V> = HashMap<K, V>;
type Variant1 = Common<u32, u64>;
type Variant2 = Common<i32, i64>;

enum Stuff {
    V1(Variant1),
    V2(Variant2),
}

impl Stuff {
    fn new(variant1: bool) -> Stuff {
        if variant1 {
            Stuff::V1(Variant1::new())
        } else {
            Stuff::V2(Variant2::new())
        }
    }

    // Example 1
    fn get<K, V>(&self) -> &Common<K, V> {
        match self {
            Stuff::V1(x) => x,
            Stuff::V2(x) => x,
        }
    }

    // Example 2
    fn get_key<K, V>(&self, key: K) -> Option<&V> {
        match self {
            Stuff::V1(x) => x.get(key),
            Stuff::V1(x) => x.get(key),
        }
    }
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=9be1386761a6192a49d9e76090ca37d8)

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:23:29
   |
21 |     fn get<K, V>(&self) -> &Common<K, V> {
   |            - this type parameter
22 |         match self {
23 |             Stuff::V1(x) => x,
   |                             ^ expected type parameter `K`, found `u32`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&std::collections::HashMap<K, V>`
              found reference `&std::collections::HashMap<u32, u64>`
   = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:30:35
   |
28 |     fn get_key<K, V>(&self, key: K) -> &V {
   |                - this type parameter
29 |         match self {
30 |             Stuff::V1(x) => x.get(key),
   |                                   ^^^ expected `&u32`, found type parameter `K`
   |
   = note:   expected reference `&u32`
           found type parameter `K`
   = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:30:29
   |
30 |             Stuff::V1(x) => x.get(key),
   |                             ^^^^^^^^^^ expected `&V`, found enum `std::option::Option`
   |
   = note: expected reference `&V`
                   found enum `std::option::Option<&u64>`

error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:31:35
   |
28 |     fn get_key<K, V>(&self, key: K) -> &V {
   |                - this type parameter
...
31 |             Stuff::V1(x) => x.get(key),
   |                                   ^^^ expected `&u32`, found type parameter `K`
   |
   = note:   expected reference `&u32`
           found type parameter `K`
   = help: type parameters must be constrained to match other types
   = note: for more information, visit https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html#traits-as-parameters
```

I would like to have an alternative that would allow me to manipulate (and get things from) the inner type of the variant without having generics all over the place.

As suggested in [How can I avoid a ripple effect from changing a concrete struct to generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912349/155423), if I can use a `Box` with a struct instead, it works:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

trait Common<K, V> {
    fn get(&self, key: &K) -> Option<&V>;
}

struct Variant1(HashMap<u32, u64>);
struct Variant2(HashMap<i32, i64>);

impl Common<u32, u64> for Variant1 {
    fn get(&self, key: &u32) -> Option<&u64> {
        self.get(key)
    }
}
impl Common<i32, i64> for Variant2 {
    fn get(&self, key: &i32) -> Option<&i64> {
        self.get(key)
    }
}

struct Stuff<K, V>(Box<dyn Common<K, V>>);

impl<K, V> Stuff<K, V> {
    fn new(variant1: bool) -> Stuff<K, V> {
        if variant1 {
            Stuff(Box::new(Variant1(HashMap::new())))
        } else {
            Stuff(Box::new(Variant2(HashMap::new())))
        }
    }
}

impl<K, V> Common<K, V> for Stuff<K, V> {
    fn get(&self, key: &K) -> Option<&V> {
        self.0.get(key)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let stuff1 = Stuff::new(true);
    let r1 = stuff1.get(&42);
    let stuff2 = Stuff::new(true);
    let r2 = stuff2.get(&42);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=ff33caef6c0e9e24e6588b80eb2dc1c9)

However, because this is no longer an enum, I cannot create the variant under one enum/struct anymore (the code above doesn't compile).

On one hand, I want to be able to create one single struct/enum that holds multiple complicated types (enum), but on the other hand I want to be able to get/access to the underlying object. I can't find a way to do both things.

Comment: Your question might be answered by the answers of [How can I avoid a ripple effect from changing a concrete struct to generic?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/44912349/155423). If not, please **[edit]** your question to explain the differences. Otherwise, we can mark this question as already answered.

Comment: It's very close but it's not the same because what I'm trying to do is a wrapper enum that hides the complexity of Variant1 and Variant2. I will try to explain better tomorrow

Comment: I don't understand what you want `get` and `get_key` to do if the actual variant doesn't match the `K` and `V` provided by the caller. What ought to happen if you have a `Stuff::V1` and you call `.get::<i32, i64>()` on it? Or, stretching a bit further, what if you call `.get::<String, &'static f64>()`?

Comment: To reiterate the curcial part of @trentcl's comment: `K` and `V` are provided by the _caller_ of the methods, and can be any types the caller chooses.

Comment: "K and V are provided by the caller of the methods": I think that's part of the thing I didn't understand. I was hoping that depending on the variant from which it was called I could simply call the underlying method and return the appropriate type. The return type only vary in type parameters after all. I think what I'm looking for is too clause to dynamic typing

Comment: "The return type only vary in type parameters after all." - There's no such thing as "only vary in type parameters". A `Vec<A>` and a `Vec<B>` are as different as `i32` and `String`, as far as the type system is concerned, no matter what A and B are.

Answer (score 1):

`HashMap<u32, u64> != HashMap<i32, i64>`

I know the key and value types are the same size, so the in memory representation will be similar, but rust won't let you cast back and fourth between the two types without using **unsafe**.

The following example does not use unsafe.

You should note that the examples in this thread are not logically sound because casting between signed and unsigned integers yields incorrect results.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;                       

struct Stuff {                                       
    map: HashMap<[u8; 4], [u8; 8]>,                  
}                                                    

impl Stuff {                                         
    fn new() -> Stuff {                              
        Stuff {                                      
            map: HashMap::new(),                     
        }                                            
    }                                                

    fn get_u32_u64(&self, key: u32) -> Option<u64> { 
        self.map                                     
            .get(&key.to_ne_bytes())                 
            .cloned()                                
            .map(u64::from_ne_bytes)                 
    }                                                

    fn get_i32_u64(&self, key: i32) -> Option<u64> { 
        self.map                                     
            .get(&key.to_ne_bytes())                 
            .cloned()                                
            .map(u64::from_ne_bytes)                 
    }                                                

    fn get_u32_i64(&self, key: u32) -> Option<i64> { 
        self.map                                     
            .get(&key.to_ne_bytes())                 
            .cloned()                                
            .map(i64::from_ne_bytes)                 
    }                                                

    fn get_i32_i64(&self, key: i32) -> Option<i64> { 
        self.map                                     
            .get(&key.to_ne_bytes())                 
            .cloned()                                
            .map(i64::from_ne_bytes)                 
    }                                                
}
```

Here is another alternative using traits.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;                                      

struct Stuff {                                                      
    map: HashMap<[u8; 4], [u8; 8]>,                                 
}                                                                   

trait StuffKey {                                                    
    fn key(self) -> [u8; 4];                                        
}                                                                   

trait StuffValue {                                                  
    fn val(val: [u8; 8]) -> Self;                                   
}                                                                   

impl Stuff {                                                        
    fn new() -> Stuff {                                             
        Stuff {                                                     
            map: HashMap::new(),                                    
        }                                                           
    }                                                               

    fn get<K: StuffKey, V: StuffValue>(&self, key: K) -> Option<V> {
        self.map.get(&key.key()).cloned().map(StuffValue::val)      
    }                                                               
}                                                                   

impl StuffKey for i32 {                                             
    fn key(self) -> [u8; 4] {                                       
        self.to_ne_bytes()                                          
    }                                                               
}                                                                   

impl StuffKey for u32 {                                             
    fn key(self) -> [u8; 4] {                                       
        self.to_ne_bytes()                                          
    }                                                               
}                                                                   

impl StuffValue for i64 {                                           
    fn val(val: [u8; 8]) -> Self {                                  
        Self::from_ne_bytes(val)                                    
    }                                                               
}                                                                   

impl StuffValue for u64 {                                           
    fn val(val: [u8; 8]) -> Self {                                  
        Self::from_ne_bytes(val)                                    
    }                                                               
}
```